# Xcode: How do I create an Image manipulation app? Move, resize and place an image

Tags: xcode, image

Hey I want to create an app that is similar to these 'face juggler' apps, and other apps in which a photo is taken of the user, then you can drag an image on top to add effects. I have seen one with sunglasses, and i would like to do one with hats (for my brand). 
So essentially I will need to be able to take a photo or select from library, then place it in, then add this image over the top which can be resized and moved, then I would need to export the final image to camera roll or facebook etc.
Does anybody know where I should start? I am quite new to this and couldn't find any guides or related questions
Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful source is the Core Image Programming Guide from Apple. In these document you will find all you have to now about image filter and image manipulation. But first you have to implement a UIImagePickerConroller. With this controller the user of your app can take a picture by using the device camera or by picking an image from the library.